# Hypothesis Testing Probability Density Estimates

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, dataset, histogram, density-estimation

Is there a good way to test an probability density estimate against observed data? I know there exist various approaches to probability density estimation and testing individual parameters of density estimates against observed data, but do not know of any approach to test a general function against data. Would some approach where the function estimate and the data are treated as histograms work?

Specifically, could one just bin the estimate into a histogram and build confidence regions of Dirichlet parameters using the multinomial distribution expression given observed data?

Comment: Histograms might give you a rough idea, but an empirical CDF (backed up by a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test will almost always work better

Comment: Where does the density estimate come from? Are you talking about a probability density from  a brand-name distribution implied by parameter estimates, or an empirically derived estimate, say from a kernel method?

Answer (score 2):

One general method of testing data against a particular probability CDF (with known parameters) is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness-of-fit test.

Suppose we have $n = 2000$ observations from $\mathsf{Gamma}(5, .2)$ in the vector `x` as follows. [The shape parameter is $5$
and the rate parameter is $0.2.]$

```
set.seed(121)
x = rgamma(2000, 5, .2)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.551  16.630  23.469  25.020  31.425  89.405 

hdr="n=2000: Sample from BETA(5, .2) with Density"
hist(x, prob=T, br=35, ylim=c(0,.045), col="wheat", main=hdr)
 curve(dgamma(x, 5, .2), add=T, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The mean of this distribution is $\mu = 5/.2 = 25,$ which
is nearly matched by the sample mean, and the population
median is $\eta = 23.35454,$ which is nearly matched by
the sample median 23.57. Similarly, the population and
sample upper quartiles are not far apart. So it seems
feasible that `x` was sampled from $\mathsf{Gamma}(5, .2).$

```
qgamma(.5, 5, .2)
[1] 23.35454
qgamma(.75, 5, .20)
[1] 31.37215
```

Perhaps most important, the K-S test does not reject the sample `x` as coming from the population $\mathsf{Gamma}(5, .2).$

```
ks.test(x, pgamma, 5, .2)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.013078, p-value = 0.8837
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The test statistic $D$ is the maximum vertical distance between
the CDF of the distribution [dashed blue] in the figure below) and the empirical CDF (ECDF) of the
the sample [orange].

```
hdr = "n==2000: GAMMA(5,.2) CDF (orange) and Sample ECDF"
plot(ecdf(x), col="orange", main = hdr)
 curve(pgamma(x, 5, .2), add=T, col="blue", lwd=2, lty="dashed")
```

[image]

However, the K-S test does reject the null hypothesis that `x` was sampled at random from $\mathsf{Gamma}(4, .16),$ which also has $\mu=25.$

```
ks.test(x, pgamma, 4, .16)$p.val
[1] 0.006478847
```

*Note:* If data may be normal, then the Shapiro-Wilk test will tend not to reject a sample from *any* normal distribution regardless of its mean or variance, and to reject non-normal samples.

```
shapiro.test(rnorm(50, 100, 15))$p.val
[1] 0.3374453
```

Comment: It's reassuring that the test does not reject the distribution you know the data were simulated from, but a more common question, perhaps the OP's, is to have somewhat messy data and some idea about brand-name distribution(s) to fit. I find that (1) the KS test seems in practice, and indeed necessarily, most sensitive in the middle of distributions and least in the tails, the converse of what is often desired (2) the KS test does not indicate why any distribution is a bad fit (and it is not designed to do that) (3) quantile-quantile plots beat formal tests for helpfulness most of the time.

Comment: In a quantile-quantile plot, to what would you compare the sample?

Comment: Such a plot compares observed quantiles with expected quantiles, or a linear scaling of such: it is just the 19th century idea of a normal probability plot (normal scores plot, probit plot) generalised

Comment: I cannot see how this answer applies to the question, because the question does not concern comparing data to a "known" CDF: it concerns comparing a "probability density **estimate**" against the data.